# MongoDB If the document's field is less than another field, increase that field by one

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is one of the documents in my collection called "ids":

```
{
    "power": 100,
    "max_power": 200
}
```

All the documents in my collection have a `power` and a `max_power`. For all of the documents, if the `power` is less than the `max_power`, I want to increase the `power` by one.

I tried:

```
await ids.updateMany({power: { $lt: 'max_power' }}, {$inc: { power: 1 }})
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare internal properties value you need to use [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) expression operator,

```
await ids.updateMany(
    { $expr: { $lt: ["$power", "$max_power"] } }, 
    { $inc: { power: 1 } }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0lZukdZfKAX)